# Extension for making Google Reader the way it was?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

To put it mildly, I'm less than enthusiastic about Google Reader's new (Oh Gawd, 20pt line spacing) interface. Is there an extension for Chrome which can put it back the way it was, at least in terms of line spacing and "useful reading area"?

Comment: Hmmm, I think I see what you mean. At least the new GMail interface includes a quick switch between the different spacing sizes. I though Reader might have that too, but can't find anything obvious.

Comment: @music2myear - Yeah. Also, for some reason my "minimalistic for gmail" still works, for the most part. On GReader, no such luck. IMHO, they really screwed it up with this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ditto! Don't know why Google loves all those whitespace.

As for your question, here is an extension for Chrome: [FIxStyleSheeet For GoogleReader](http://www.addictivetips.com/internet-tips/restore-google-reader-feed-list-spacing-with-fixstylesheet/), or if you want a userscript, check out [Google Reader compact](http://sumtips.com/2011/11/compact-layout-new-google-reader.html). I am using the userscript since it does the same as the extension minus the memory usage.

Comment: Apparently, most of their original GReader team left and the new people  have no clue what they're doing. One of the original authors of GReader wrote a post (found a link on HN) saying how the new Reader is horrible. Thanks for the links, I'll check them out.

Comment: Yup, the FSS for GREader works nicely. Thanks!